# is there a such thing as a 2D or 3D memory layout for modern computer memory architectures?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

my understanding is that a 2D NxM matrix is stored contiguously as a 1D array of NxM length. However natural world is clearly not like it. e.g., human eyes perceive geometric distance, which means that recognizing (i,j), (i+1,j), (i,j+1) are nearby each other is very efficient. However when stored as a row-major 1D array, (i,j) and (i,j+1) are close in memory, but (i+1,j) is not.

I wonder if a more efficient memory layout based on geometric distance have been discussed in computer science literatures. It seems that naively one can introduce a two-dimensional or three-dimensional address pointer to leverage such a memory architecture...

Comment: Check out Z-order coding, also called Morton coding.  Remember that any layout you choose must include a mapping from the layout order to linear addresses that has a fast, cheap implementation.

Comment: @Gene  Never knew that prior to your remarks. Many thanks! The wiki page on Z-order curve is very informative. I had no idea that this has been implemented behind  the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

There are classes of address mapping that allows for better spatial locality for 2D and 3D data sets.

[Z-order curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) have long been very important in graphics processing when sampling textures. What makes it better than other schemes is the dead simple address translation between ND and linear address.

There is also [Hilbert curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) that have somewhat better locality properties. While not as widely used in graphics because translation costing a bit more, making it a bad trade-off for the domain, it is supposedly popular in other domains.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. but from your answer as well as Gene's, there isn't a notion of true 2d or 3d memory addressing in CS literatures right? One relies on an algorithm level a clever mapping that addresses locality issue.

Comment: @Rain Not that I'm aware. Not my area of expertise. Perhaps better ask on electrical engineering forums.